# How to properly replace an owned collection of items?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I receive an exception when trying to replace the owned collection with the one I receive through API (EF Core 6).

`System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'Product' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.`

Here is my model configuration:

```csharp
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

```csharp
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>(x =>
{
    x.HasKey(e => e.Id);
    x.Property(e => e.Name);
});
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>(x =>
{
    x.HasKey(e => e.Id);
    x.OwnsMany(e => e.OrderItems, p =>
    {
        p.ToTable("OrderItems")
            .WithOwner();
        p.HasOne(e => e.Product).WithMany();
        p.Property(e => e.Quantity);
    });
});
```

Act:

```csharp
//these are updated items received through API
var newItems = new List<OrderItem>
{
    new OrderItem{  Product = new Product { Id = 2}, Quantity = 2},
    new OrderItem{  Product = new Product { Id = 3}, Quantity = 3}
};

var existingOrder = _dbContext.Orders
    .Include(o => o.OrderItems).ThenInclude(i => i.Product)
    .Single(o => o.Id == 1);
// Existing OrderItems are already referencing Product with Id 2 

existingOrder.OrderItems = newItems;

// Error occurs because Product with Id = 2 was already tracked 
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I know that the issue might be resolved by replacing `Product` with `ProductId` within my `OrderItem` class but I would rather prefer to keep my domain model as it is.

What is the best practice to perform such update?

Answer (score 0):

it's all about understanding of the modeling. You can create a model response to update also, but just have to update manually by calling it.

you have existingOrder from the query include, then include like this I guess

```
var existingOrder = ...
existingOrder.OrderItems.Update(yourentity_OrderItem);
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

So this mean you have to retrieve each Product.id by a for, and update each new items, then savechanges.